# Export Posts Without Categories In An XML File

Tags: posts, categories, import, export, xml

I have an xml file with posts, authors, images, and other content that I am importing successfully into a new site, but I would like to remove all categories from posts and make them uncategorized at the time of importing or before. I tried removing the categories manually from the xml file in vs code but this seemed quite tedious as there are 100s of posts and many category tags. Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you tried using tools to modify the XML rather than doing it by hand?

Comment: I am importing through the tools importer area, but haven’t located any plugins or features for editing the categories out of posts during the import.

Comment: I was trying to convey that an XML file isn't a WordPress specific thing, you can use generic tools that have nothing to do with WordPress to make your modifications rather than doing them by hand. These tools are not plugins or features you can add to a WordPress install, they could be a desktop application, code, or command line changes

Comment: I see. Thank you for suggesting. I haven’t worked with xml files much before and am going to research tools suitable for this. I’m there is a script that could be written to clean the file of categories.

Comment: The term relationships table is what associates posts with a term (a category in this case). The uncategorized category is term ID 1, the `object_id` is the associated post ID.